# How to view and edit data from multiple tables in a DataGrid with EF?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework

I have 2 tables: Orders and Customers. Orders is related to Customers by the IdCustomer foreign key.

Problem: I want to show in the DataGrid the values from both tables and want to be able to edit the data belonging to the Orders table.

I managed to show and edit in the grid the Orders table, but how do I include the data from the Customers table?

```
this.grdData.ItemsSource = context.Orders;

private void btnSave_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually, if you have a fk in your table, you'll have a relationship in your entity. If you don't have it, you should add it.

The best approach is to create a ViewModel class for what you want to show from both entities:

```
public class OrderViewModel {
    public string CustomerName{ get; set; }
    public decimal OrderTotal { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
}
```

Then you need to execute a query that retrieves all the information:

```
var query = from o in dataContext.Orders
            select new ViewModel {
                                   CustomerName = o.Customer.Name,                                                            
                                   OrderTotal = o.Total,
                                   Date = o.Date
                                 };
```

and use it as the data source for the Grid.

If by any chances you don't have the relationship in your model, you can do a less straight forward query:

```
var query = from o in dataContext.Orders
            join c in dataContext.Customers on o.CustomerId equals c.Id
            select new ViewModel {
                                   CustomerName = c.Name,                                                            
                                   OrderTotal = o.Total,
                                   Date = o.Date
                                  };
```

Comment: With this aproach I copy the data from A to B, edit it in B and then copy it back to A. Thats a lot of extra work. Cant I edit the data in A?

Comment: Do you have the relationship between the entities in your model?

Comment: Yes, I have the relationship.

Comment: Have you tried bind the grid to your orders and use `Customer.Name` as a column expression?

Comment: Yeah. It worked. Thanks. I had AutoGenerateColumns="True" for the grid, so I thought that I dont have the data from customers since the columns from Customers have not appeared. Asking specifically for the Customer.Name column works :D